# How to force Sphinx to use Python 3.x interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I try to create documentation for a project written with Python 3.x. [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html) is *the* tool I want to use and, according to the [official site](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/changes.html), its last version 1.1.2 is compatible with [Python 3.1+](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/changes.html). My OS is Archlinux, a Linux distribution which uses Python 3.2+ as the default Python package.

The installation and configuration is straight forward (`easy_install -U Sphinx` then `sphinx-quickinstall`) and I was never asked to choose between the 2.x or 3.x Python interpreter. But when I ask Sphinx to create the documentation of my project, my code is analyzed as if I wrote it for Python 2.x.

Is Sphinx ready for Python 3.x? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: The best answer is pavan's: simply change the Makefile with:
 
SPHINXBUILD   = python3 -msphinx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this exact same problem last night, when I came across your question. — I am also on Arch.

I guess the problem could be a number of different things, but the solution for me was that I had the Python 2 version of the `python-distribute` package installed and therefore had `easy_install-2.7` not `easy_install-3.2`.

I believe in my case the wrong version of `python-distribute` was installed by my attempt to previously install Sphinx from pacman (which installs version 1.0.8), so uninstalling Sphinx and all subsequently unneeded dependencies `pacman -Rsu python-sphinx` and then installing `python-distribute` got me the right version of `easy_install`, then reinstalling Sphinx with `easy_install` and the Sphinx installation works as expected.

<strike>If you have other things that depend on `python-distribute` then the process may be a little different. But start by just trying to remove `python-distribute` and work from there.</strike>

Scrap that last part. It's too early in the morning and I wasn't thinking straight! `python2-distribute` and `python-distribute` are seperate packages which I believe can co-exist. So, if this is your problem all you need to do is check you have `python-distribute` (not "2"), if not install it, and then ensure you use `easy_install-3.2` to install Sphinx.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 23):

**Installation:** Install sphinx with *pip* for *python3*(*pip3* like that).

```
    pip3 install -U sphinx
```

**Building:** `Makefile`(linux/Mac) changes.

```
    SPHINXBUILD   = python -msphinx
```

In above line in Makefile change *python* to *python3(or python3.x)* like

```
   SPHINXBUILD   = python3 -msphinx
```

if default python is pointing to 2.x version
   python.

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu, `python3-sphinx` is a separate package. In my case, I needed to install python3-sphinx:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sphinx
```

You can probably run both on a machine, but I just removed the old one:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-sphinx
```

My old makefile worked just fine with my Python 3 code after this.

Comment: On macOS, uninstalling version 2.7 and only installing 3.5 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 9):

I'm from the future (2020).

I've had issues making Sphinx play nicely with a specific python interpreter and Ubuntu. Just thought an up to date answer might help others wandering here.

===================================

So, the first thing to understand is that if you use the automated build/installation option, you should still double-check that you're getting what you think you should.

For instance, running (as suggested at the top of [Sphinx's doc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html))

```
apt install python3-sphinx
```

and then running `sphinx-quickstart` in a directory where you want to build the auto-doc will work. However, it will use Sphinx 1.6.7 (at the time of writing the latest Sphinx version is 3.0.3), since the repo is apparently not maintained. Then if you want to use some Sphinx extensions (like `sphinx-js`, which was my case) then you may be in for a bit of a surprise.

So I would recommend using those automated packaged install only for straightforward use cases or testing or prototyping.

=========================================

### **A better approach**

Install SPHINX using pip (pip3 for Py3)

```
pip3 install -U sphinx
```

Now you have the lastest pip3 release and it is working with a specific, known interpreter. You can double-check with `pip3 list`

### **Init you project's autodoc**

If doing the above, `sphinx-quickstart` may not work: command not found. I am guessing that the `apt install` takes care of putting some scripts, such as sphinx-quickstart, in the path.

However you can do:

```
python3 -m sphinx.cmd.quickstart
```

in the root of your documentation's directory. This will act much like sphinx-quickstart. If you want the more features, you may need to add extensions to the newly created conf.py. For exemple (see Sphinx's doc for details):

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages']
```

### **Building your doc**

Then finally, `make html` if installed this way will not work out of the box. However, you can instead launch the full command instead:

[python interpreter] -m sphinx.cmd.build -b [builder type] [path-to-conf.py] [path-output-directoy]

For exemple:

```
python3 -m sphinx.cmd.build -b html /home/anonymous/PycharmProjects/DocstringDemo/docstrings /home/anonymous/PycharmProjects/DocstringDemo/docstrings/_build
```

Which is pretty much what the makefile itself does.

So now you have Sphinx installed with a specific interpreter

Comment: Thanks for this, it made the trick. The only I needed to do is NOT to run `python3 -m sphinx.cmd.quickstart` since there is already a conf.py file on my root

Answer (score 6):

I'm on Ubunut and had the same problem. I won't use *Josh_P* or *Nicolas* answer because..

- I don't want to change my PYTHON path.
- I don't want to uninstall python-sphinx because I need it with older Projects.

So i fixed it with this little script called `sphinx3-build`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Same as /usr/bin/sphinx-build but with different
interpreter
"""

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sphinx import main, make_main
    if sys.argv[1:2] == ['-M']:
        sys.exit(make_main(sys.argv))
    else:
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

It's the same as sphinx-build but with a different interpreter.
In the Makefile I changed the following line:

```
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx3-build
```

Now copy the file to the `/usr/bin/` folder:

```
sudo cp sphinx3-build /usr/bin/
```

This worked for me. You could also use it locally for one project only by placing the
script into the same folder as the Makefile and set `SPHINXBUILD` to 
`./sphinx3-build`.

Comment: Thanks for that! This works fine! I thought switching the general /usr/bin/python symbolic link from /usr/bin/python2 to /usr/bin/python3 was a good idea, since I am only using python3 - well, it wasn't.. other progs then produced errors due to wrong python syntax.. ^^ That's a neater solution.

Answer (score 2):

A similar solution to those already offered is to put the call to sphinx.main() right into the SPHINXBUILD variable in the Makefile:

```
SPHINXBUILD   = python3 -c "import sys,sphinx;sys.exit(sphinx.main(sys.argv))"
```

The sphinx-generated "User-friendly check for sphinx-build" block of code fails then so I just removed it. This solution was preferable to me since it didn't require a separate script nor the removal of any python installation or sphinx module.

Comment: This unfortunately does nothing for me.

Comment: @oarfish a very similar command could be used in the make.bat file if you are on windows.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm on OSX.

Comment: this doesnt work even for OSX, gives error for >sphinx has no attribute 'main'

Comment: @John you could have elaborated a bit more... but you helped me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Sphinx is installed only with Python-2 support. Although there are various ways to install Sphinx for python3, just use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create a custom environment that uses python3 by default.

`virtualenv -p /path/to/python-3` foo

And inside the virtualenv install Sphinx:

`pip install Sphinx`

As a bonus, this approach allows you to create custom environments for different projects.

PS. You might want to consider using [virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper).

Comment: Thank you for this idea. You say "there are various ways to install Sphinx for python3" : can you give me some explanations since I can't use - for the moment - virtualenv ?

Comment: @suizokukan Well, it depends on the platform and its distro. For example Gentoo GNU/Linux supports parallel installations of Python out of the box. It also gives version prefixes to the executable tools (I currently have Python-2.7 and Python-3.2 enabled on my machine and therefore installed created two easy-install commands : `easy-install-2.7` and `easy-install-3.2`). So what platform/distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using an (up-to-date) Archlinux; on this distribution the command `python` is linked to Python 3.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

When I searched for an answer, this is the site that came up over and over. I'm thinking the answer is not easy to find because everyone else understands sphinx better than I can figure out. But if any is still searching for an answer, this is what eventually I ended up with:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3

sudo apt-get install sqlite3

sudo apt-get install idle3

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

sudo apt-get install python3-docutils

sudo apt-get install python3-jinja2

sudo apt-get install python3-pygments

sudo pip3 install Sphinx

The key was I was missing the fact that there was a pip3. I also update the system before adding a package as habit.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sphinx simply uses the "python" command as interpreter. But according to the Makefile, you can specify your own with the PYTHON option, when running `make` for installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; `make html` should(?) probably call `python`, id est, on my system, Python 3.2.2 - and that's exactly what I expect from Sphinx. But the result I get shows that another interpreter is called (python2 ?) even if I don't understand why.

Comment: Write in a terminal ``ls -l /usr/bin/python``, it will print your default interpreter version.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but `ls -l /usr/bin/python` shows me that `/usr/bin/python` is linked to `python3`, id est on my system, to Python 3.2.2.

Comment: If you're sure the interpreter is Python 2.x (have you verified if another version of Python is installed btw?), you can install Sphinx again, setting the ``PYTHON`` option to ``python3`` (see the [easy_install doc](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#controlling-build-options)).

Comment: Explicitly setting the interpreter doesn't do anything on macOS.