# automodule breaking with Python return type annotations

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to document my Python 3 code with Sphinx. Here's my example file:

```
class MyClass:
    """
    Class description
    """

    def get_name(self) -> str:
        """
        Returns the name of this object as a string.
        """
        return "Jim"
```

And my directive in one of my .rst files is:

```
.. autoclass:: my_class.MyClass
   :members:
```

But when I run `sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html` (version 1.1.3), the type annotation `->` breaks:

```
    def command_name(self) -> str:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I get Sphinx to recognize type annotations?

Edit: My python3 version is 3.2.3.

Comment: I think you need https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-autodoc-annotation/1.0

Comment: I'd like to avoid the extension if possible. Also, that module requires 3.3+.

Comment: From the docs it seems you require the extension to do what you want. I don't think upgrading to python 3.4 would hurt.

Answer (score 0):

While automodule may not recognize Python 3 annotations, the build should not break from using them. The issue in my case was that Sphinx was using my python2.7 interpreter:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):on_osdp_messages
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
```

This probably means you have the wrong version of Sphinx installed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015225/sphinx-and-python-3-x-how-force-sphinx-to-use-python-3-x-interpreter/) ([in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23922391/461834) I needed to use a different Debian package).