# Sphinx appends a 0 to my reference id

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, citations

I have a .rst document containing the following lines...

```
This example goes over the  analysis found the author's paper [Hughes2017]_.

.. [Hughes2017] Hughes, M., Olsen, J., *On the potential of organic Rankine cycles for recovering waste heat from the exhaust gases of a piston aero-engine*, Asia-Pacific International Symposium on Aerospace Technology, Seoul, Korea, 2017.
```

When I use Sphinx to produce a .html file from this .rst file, the reference comes out as [Hughes20170] (both in text and in the reference list). Could anybody explain why this is?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Python 3.6 / Sphinx 1.5.6. I obtain the right `[Hughes2017]`. Any unusual extensions in the `conf.py` file? Have you cleaned the build? `make clean && make html`

Comment: I have run `make clean && make html` but I still get the same problem. I haven't edited my conf.py file beyond adding 'numpydoc' to extensions. My MAKEFILE has SPHINXBUILD = sphinx3-build, which otherwise seems to be working fine, as recommended in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/24675806/8917310

Comment: When executing `make html`, is sphinx mentioning errors and/or warnings?

Comment: it comes up with lots of warnings about non existing documents which I believe is due to me using autosummary, because it then creates these documents and the html files are created fine. That's the only warning it shows though.

Comment: can you give the version of sphinx?

Comment: Sphinx v1.6.6. I have since uninstalled python-sphinx and the custom sphinx3-build file and am using python3-sphinx which builds great but with this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! My question was a little misleading because actually the text above was in the docstring of a module. I was then using automodule in an rst file in my /doc folder to call the docstring of that module and it was appending the 0 to the citation. If I remove the References heading from the docstring and place it instead in the actual rst file it stops appending the 0.

Comment: this could be an `autodoc` bug, could you [open a ticket](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues) ?

Comment: Issue has been opened. 
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4782