# How can I get sphinx to use Python 3 as an interpreter?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I'm building documentation with sphinx. I use a `conda` setup and have `py27` and `py36` version of python that I switch between. On running `sphinx-build ./source ./build` I get the following error:

```
WARNING: /home/b3053674/Documents/pytseries/docs/source/index.rst:14: (WARNING/2) autodoc: failed to import module u'pytseries.core'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b3053674/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 657, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/b3053674/Documents/pytseries/pytseries/core.py", line 193
    ts = TimeSeries(**args, feature=self.feature)
                          ^
```

Note that `**args` is a dictionary and that none of my tests give me a syntax error.

After looking again it looks as though the docs for my Python 3 project is being built with a python2.7 interpreter (even though my `py36` env is active). I suspect this may be reeking havoc but I can't get sphinx to use my python 3 interpretor.

So how can I get sphinx to use Python 3 as an interpreter?

### Edit

also node I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015225/how-to-force-sphinx-to-use-python-3-x-interpreter) question and have installed `python3-sphinx`

Comment: Whenever I have a problem with virtual environments, I delete it and start over. I use only pip to install packages (do not use both setuptools and pip, that only ends badly). I don't activate, but instead use the filepath to Python in my commands, e.g., `env/bin/python` or `make html SPHINXBUILD=../env/bin/sphinx-build`. I don't use conda. Packaging is hard enough without another factor to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a "Anaconda3" installer, this should work by default.

Else, from https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages

```
conda install sphinx -n py36_env
```

where `py36_env` is the name of a Python 3 environment.

Alternatively,

```
python3 -m pip install --user sphinx
```

should work as well.

Then, edit the Makefile to replace the line

```
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx-build
```

by

```
SPHINXBUILD   = python3 -m sphinx
```