# Jenkins sphinx-build not found

Tags: jenkins, python-sphinx

I'm using default sphinx-quickstart and Ubuntu 18.01

I'm having this issue with Jenkins when I try to do `make html`

```
/bin/sh: 1: sphinx-build: not found
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'html' failed
```

It works fine when I do the `make html` while in a terminal...

What could be the issue?

More information: I'm using the same user (tested with `whoami`) and I have installed sphinx using `pip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround based on one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015225/how-to-force-sphinx-to-use-python-3-x-interpreter)

I changed the `SPHINXBUILD` to `SPHINXBUILD   = python -m sphinx`. I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but at least it works.

I'm pretty sure my original bug has something to do with `make` and `sh` executing on its own context and not finding `sphinx-build`. If someone has a better answer, please post :)